# How to integrate offline Unity simulation with Canvas LMS

Tags: unity-game-engine, scorm, lti, lms, xapi

Im thinking xAPI would be the way to go here (though need to research more).
Seems like LTI not the way, as this is more like an exercise than a separate app?
Seems SCORM would require the simulation to be HTML and embedded in the LMS?

We are using Canvas LMS.
Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you, SCORM would not work, as it requires you to be online. xAPI has the capability to store data locally, and then send this information once it gets an internet connection. There was a good presentation on how this was done at iFest back in 2020 I believe. Look up the iFest presentations made by eduworks for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a largely subjective question so may not be the best fit here, but I can write some words.

- Agree SCORM is probably not the best fit, there is likely a way to shoehorn it in somehow but it isn't going to be a great use of that particular delivery method.
- I would not necessarily dismiss LTI as an option here, but not dismissing it really engenders more questions. It is less about the type of activity in this case, than what you hope to get back in terms of data. LTI is perfectly well suited for the launch use case for different types of experiences, but generally provides nothing in regards to how to record data back to the launching system in any particularly interoperable way. So, if you are most concerned about the launch moment and not about data capture then LTI is still on the table.
- If you need launch and data capture then I think xAPI is probably a reasonable approach, and Canvas likely supports packages based on a `tincan.xml` file and this gives you both a launch mechanism and the data capture possibility provided by leveraging an LRS through xAPI. Note that these types of packages are based on a set of guidelines that are no longer maintained, were never peer reviewed, and are known to not be great.
- The best option would be to use [cmi5](https://rusticisoftware.com/cmi5/) because it provides for a defined launch methodology, records data via xAPI, has a defined information model, is on a standards path, has been peer reviewed, is actively maintained, and is starting to have better tooling around it than the Tin Can guidelines. **But** adoption is still pretty limited, you would have to contact Canvas support to know whether they support it or when they plan to.

Comment: Thanks Brian! At the moment, we are going the route of talking directly to the LMS's API, using OAuth to authenticate the user. So, not using LTI, SCORM, or xAPI.